# Installing MELPA on Emacs 28.2

Tags: emacs24, melpa

I am an Emacs newbie and I am trying to install MELPA on my emacs 28.3. But the issue is my .emacs.d folder is empty. Can someon please explain to me how to go about

I literally have no idea what to do, should I initialize the

```
init.el
```

myself?